# How do i resolve this JSONObject issue

Tags: asp.net, json, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, json.net

I am following an article to use web services in unity3d. I am complete beginner and unfamiliar with webservices and I have basic understanding of how it works.

I have tried using JsonUtiltiy lib but there is no function for JSONObject in it too.

[here is the article i am following](https://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/04/calling-a-web-service-from-a-unity3d-scene.html)

list of errors i am getting

[image: list of errors i am getting]

Comment: Can we see the code related to the error? Also consider that the article is of 2012, so it could be a bit outdated.

Comment: JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);



        // Our outer object is an array



        if (jo.type != JSONObject.Type.ARRAY)

            return;

Comment: and everywhere JSONOject is being used

Comment: Have you tried using [this asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-object-710) or [reading this wiki](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/JSONObject)

Comment: yeah ik. but is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONObject is not a class implemented in the unity editor.
To use it, you require to download its implementation in your project (Assets Folder).

As stated in the [article you reported](https://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/04/calling-a-web-service-from-a-unity3d-scene.html) the JSONObject can be found in Unity Wiki.

> I started off bringing down a JSON-reading implementation for their
>   Wiki (be sure to add the Nullable class definition, listed further
>   down the page)

I see that the link on the article is dead, but you can find the asset he mentioned at the following links.

Download and import it from the [Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-object-710)
Download and import from [github repository](https://github.com/mtschoen/JSONObject)

You need to import them and use in your project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23138273)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not assertive enough. The answer is: to solve the issue it is required to download the asset I linked. I also commented that, and converted it in an answer when I was sure it was the solution. Just updated the answer to be more clear.